# Android studio AUTOMATICALLY closes after indexing project

Tags: android, android-studio

After my project indexing is done, the Android Studio shuts shown.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try clearing your cache from **File>InvalidateCache/restart**

Also... Clean project and rebuild. Do let me know if it changes anything for you.